# Why is the Wasserstein distance not used in Variational Inference

Tags: machine-learning, autoencoders, kullback-leibler, wasserstein, variational-inference

I just started learning the concept of variational inference in the context of variational Autoencoder, so please excuse me if the answer is obvious. I would like to know why traditionally, KL-divergence is used instead of the Wasserstein distance in the Loss-function of a VAE.

Comment: KLD arises in the derivation in the marginal log-likelihood of the VAE model. See the Kingma and Welling paper "Auto-Encoding Variational Bayes" https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6114.pdf

Comment: KL divergence is most commonly used because of it can be computed in closed form for a substantial set of probability distributions.

Comment: But to answer the title question: it is https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C9&q=wasserstein+variational+inference&oq=wasserstein+va